# iOS app crash on launch after installing from TestFlight

Tags: ios, testflight

I'm adding a new target to an existing iOS app.
I tested the new app with simulators and devices before uploading a new build to TestFlight and
asked some of my colleagues to test it through TestFlight.
The problem is that for 2 of my testers the app crashes as soon as they launch it and the rest have encountered no such issue.

Here is the part of the log related to the crash:

```
    Thread 3 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191e0dec4 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191d291d8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 136 (pthread.c:1458)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000191c7d844 abort + 100 (abort.c:110)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000191dd67d4 abort_message + 128 (abort_message.cpp:76)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000191dd69c4 demangling_terminate_handler() + 296 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:66)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000191d3e258 _objc_terminate() + 124 (objc-exception.mm:701)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000191de3304 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000191de329c std::terminate() + 44 (cxa_handlers.cpp:87)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000191ce3198 _dispatch_client_callout + 36 (object.m:498)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000191c8ba3c _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp + 412 (inline_internal.h:2484)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000191c8b190 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 600 (queue.c:803)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000191c97fa4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 376 (inline_internal.h:2525)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000191c98770 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 128 (queue.c:6628)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191d32b48 _pthread_wqthread + 212 (pthread.c:2364)
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191d35760 start_wqthread + 8
```

Can someone please help me make sense of the log and explain to me what might be causing the crash?

UPDATE: 
I ran the app in release mode on two devices and no crash or error found.
I added some more info from the crash log.

```
Date/Time:           2020-05-05 14:01:31.4587 -0500
Launch Time:         2020-05-05 14:01:30.4977 -0500
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.3.1 (17D50)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    4.01.02
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  3

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x192016a48 __exceptionPreprocess + 220 (NSException.m:199)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x191d3dfa4 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x19206c360 _CFThrowFormattedException + 112 (CFObject.m:1990)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1920756b4 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:].cold.4 + 48
4   CoreFoundation                  0x191f0373c -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 240 (NSPlaceholderDictionary.m:70)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x191ef55d0 +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 64 (NSDictionary.m:604)
6   AFNetworking                    0x104fdbe04 -[AFURLSessionManager URLSession:task:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:] + 1160 (AFURLSessionManager.m:177)
7   CFNetwork                       0x19540d90c __68-[NSURLSession delegate_task:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 136 (Session.mm:598)
8   Foundation                      0x1923db3a0 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16 (NSOperation.m:1541)
9   Foundation                      0x1922e50c8 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 100 (NSOperation.m:1560)
10  Foundation                      0x1923dd628 __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__ + 20 (NSOperation.m:2184)
11  Foundation                      0x1922e4d60 -[NSOperation start] + 732 (NSOperation.m:2201)
12  Foundation                      0x1923de020 __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__ + 20 (NSOperation.m:2215)
13  Foundation                      0x1923ddaec __NSOQSchedule_f + 180 (NSOperation.m:2226)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x191c957dc _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 104 (queue.c:525)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x191ce3184 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:495)
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x191c8ba3c _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp + 412 (inline_internal.h:2484)
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x191c8b190 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 600 (queue.c:803)
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x191c97fa4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 376 (inline_internal.h:2525)
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x191c98770 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 128 (queue.c:6628)
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x191d32b48 _pthread_wqthread + 212 (pthread.c:2364)
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x191d35760 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191dec634 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191debaa0 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000191f94288 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 216 (CFRunLoop.c:2575)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000191f8f3a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1444 (CFRunLoop.c:2931)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000191f8eadc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
5   GraphicsServices                0x000000019bf2f328 GSEventRunModal + 104 (GSEvent.c:2246)
6   UIKitCore                       0x000000019609c63c UIApplicationMain + 1936 (UIApplication.m:4773)
7   F********                       0x0000000104f4b6d4 main + 76 (main.m:14)
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000191e18360 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191d35758 start_wqthread + 0 (pthread_dependency.c:69)

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191d35758 start_wqthread + 0 (pthread_dependency.c:69)

Thread 3 name:
Thread 3 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191e0dec4 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191d291d8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 136 (pthread.c:1458)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000191c7d844 abort + 100 (abort.c:110)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000191dd67d4 abort_message + 128 (abort_message.cpp:76)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000191dd69c4 demangling_terminate_handler() + 296 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:66)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000191d3e258 _objc_terminate() + 124 (objc-exception.mm:701)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000191de3304 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000191de329c std::terminate() + 44 (cxa_handlers.cpp:87)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000191ce3198 _dispatch_client_callout + 36 (object.m:498)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000191c8ba3c _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp + 412 (inline_internal.h:2484)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000191c8b190 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 600 (queue.c:803)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000191c97fa4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 376 (inline_internal.h:2525)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000191c98770 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 128 (queue.c:6628)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191d32b48 _pthread_wqthread + 212 (pthread.c:2364)
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191d35760 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191d35758 start_wqthread + 0 (pthread_dependency.c:69)

Thread 5 name:
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191dec634 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191debaa0 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000191f94288 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 216 (CFRunLoop.c:2575)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000191f8f3a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1444 (CFRunLoop.c:2931)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000191f8eadc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001922ce784 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 228 (NSRunLoop.m:374)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001922ce664 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88 (NSRunLoop.m:421)
7   UIKitCore                       0x0000000196134e80 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 152 (UIEventFetcher.m:637)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001923ff09c __NSThread__start__ + 848 (NSThread.m:724)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191d31d8c _pthread_start + 156 (pthread.c:896)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191d3576c thread_start + 8

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191d35758 start_wqthread + 0 (pthread_dependency.c:69)

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191d35758 start_wqthread + 0 (pthread_dependency.c:69)

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191d35758 start_wqthread + 0 (pthread_dependency.c:69)

Thread 3 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000191de65d8   x5: 0x000000016b06a960   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x000000016b06b000   x9: 0xd728e66b90d236e5  x10: 0x0000000191d29150  x11: 0x000000000000000b
   x12: 0x00000001ca117080  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000011
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000002603  x21: 0x000000016b06a960  x22: 0x000000016b06b0e0  x23: 0x000000016b06b0e0
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000000000134  x26: 0x00000001daa99380  x27: 0x000000016b06b180
   x28: 0x00000000000005ff   fp: 0x000000016b06a8c0   lr: 0x0000000191d291d8
    sp: 0x000000016b06a8a0   pc: 0x0000000191e0dec4 cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

Comment: Anything may cause a crash. I'd suggest you to always test the app in release mode too, not only in debug, cause some bugs may appear in release mode only.

Comment: Unfortunately your log shows nothing :(

Comment: You should try to reproduce a crash on your device to understand when and because of what it happens

Comment: You need to provide more information - the exception message if any would help.